# Continuous functions and intervals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

It is known that the image of an interval $I$ by continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is another interval $f(I)$. If the interval is compact, that is, closed and bounded, then so is $f(I)$. However, in general $I$ and $f(I)$ can be of different types.

I am trying to study which situations may arise, and find examples or a proof of why a certain case is impossible. For instance, the case $I$ is a bounded open interval and $f(I)$ an open, unbounded interval is possible; it is enough to consider the function $f(x) = 1/x$ and $I = (0,1)$. However, I'm having some troubles with the case $I$ closed and unbounded. I think $f(I)$ cannot be an open interval, but mainly because it seems impossible to draw. How could I proceed to prove this is impossible? I thought about dividing the cases $f(I)$ bounded and unbounded, but I'm stuck at this point. If I am in the wrong, a counterexample would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the function $f:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ one of those examples you are looking for? The interval $I=[0,+\infty)$ is closed unbounded and $f(I)=\mathbb{R}$ is open.

Comment: @Balloon I was thinking in the case of $I\ne \mathbb{R}$, but obviusly this is a valid example. If you could help with the case $I\ne \mathbb{R}$ I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, I will post an answer with the same idea, namely the function $\sin$ allowing to have a continuous function $f=\sin\cdot g$ whose graph oscillates between those of $g$ and $-g$: it suffices to take $g:[0,+\infty[\to \mathbb{R}$ a strictly increasing function with $g(0)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=L<+\infty$ to construct the desired example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+x}$. Then $f(I)=(-1,1)$.

Comment: Lots of thanks!!Now that I see it, is certainly was drawable

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I thought about the other cases I was trying to study and your function helped to find examples $f(I)$ open and unbounded and $f(I) = [a,b)$, just defining a continuous piecewise function using yor $f$ and  $g(x) = x$ and $g$ constant, so thanks again. I have one last case, which is $I$ bounded and semiopen and $f(I)$ open and bounded.  May I ask for help again? Should be a new question?

Comment: I can give you a hint, which would be to first find a continuous bijection $\varphi:[0,1)\to[0,+\infty)$ and then try to arrange the $f$ of the above answer with $\varphi$ to create such a function.

Comment: $\tan(\pi x/2)$ could be $\varphi$, but then?

Comment: Yes! And then you can try to show that $h=f\circ\varphi$ is an example you are looking for.

Comment: thanks again, now I see it clearly: first $\varphi$ brings $[0,1)$ to $[0,\infty]$ and then $f$ brings $[0,\infty]$ to $(-1,1)$.